# Can't start a Jupyter Nobebook in Linux [Errno30] in 'slave disk'

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, permissions, jupyter-lab

I trying to migrate to Linux. One important issue is to keep my workflow.

In Windows, I have two disks, and many projects directories in the secondary disk. For each project I have many Jupyter notebooks in each project directory. To start I navigate to the aimed project, start a terminal there, and start a Jupyter session.

I finding difficulties doing the same using Linux (Ubuntu). I'm using 'Double Commander' to navigate between 'medias'. I can start the Jupyter session in a specific directory, however, when I try to start a notebook I get the Error below.

[image]

It says 'Read-only' file system, but it appears I have all permissions...

[image]

How can deal with this problem?